# Method available in android source code but not when coding?

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

When I check the source code for WIFIP@PManager class https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.java
I see that there is a method setDeviceName but in my android code when I get `WifiP2pManager wifip2pman = (WifiP2pManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);`

wifip2pman doesn't provide the setDeviceName method!?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That method is marked with the `@hide` annotation, meaning that it is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: You could, but should not.  Hidden methods may be altered or removed from future versions of Android, potentially breaking your app.